# Bézout's Identity - Is My Understanding Correct?

Tags: number-theory

We've learned about Bézout's Identity recently and have not established the following:

> the greatest common divisor d is the smallest positive integer that can be written as ax + by

which is a part of the Identity according to Wikipedia.

First, does that sentence mean that if

$gcd(a,b) \ne 1 \Rightarrow$ there are no $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that $ax + by = 1$

and second, how does one proof that the first is true?

Comment: First: yes, Second: do you know some basic ring theory?

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't know anything about ring theory, I think, but I'd like to see more ways to prove it.

Comment: @MeikVtune Please, if you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, you should think about why that's true. For instance, suppose $\gcd(a,b) > 1$ and note $\gcd(a,b) \mid a,b$. Hence $\gcd(a,b) \mid ax+by$, which implies $|ax+by| \geq \gcd(a,b) > 1$.

As for a proof, have you tried Wikipedia? Usually, you'd start with a set that contains all numbers of the form $ax+by$, take the smallest element of that set and conclude (with some work) that this element is $\gcd(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $q$ be the smallest positive integer that can be written $q=a x + b y$. Let $n\in {\mathbb Z}$ be any integer that can be written $n = a u + b v$. By euclidean division, we get $n = p q + r$ with $0\le r < q$. It follows
that
$$r = a (u - p x) + b (v - p y)$$
We cannot have $r > 0$ because this would contradict the minimality of $q$, hence $r=0$, which implies that $q$ divides $n$.

As a consequence, $q$ divides $a = a\cdot 1 + b\cdot 0$ and $b = a\cdot 0 + b\cdot 1$. Conversely every number that divides both $a$ and $b$ divides $q=a x + b y$, so $q = gcd(a, b)$

Answer (score 0):

No, the sentence does *not* mean that $\gcd(a,b)\neq1\implies$ there are no integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+by=1$. It *implies* that this last statement is true, but it doesn't *mean* that.

On the other and, if $x,y\in\mathbb Z$, then every common divisor $d$ of $a$ and $b$ divides $ax+by$. So, if $ax+by>0$, since $\gcd(a,b)\mid ax+by$, $ax+by\geqslant\gcd(a,b)$. So, all that remains to be proved is that $\gcd(a,b)$ *can* be written as $ax+by$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb Z$. It is better to explain with a concrete example. Suppose that $a=46$ and that $b=14$. Then $\gcd(a,b)=2$ and this can be proved usin Euclid's algorithm:\begin{align}46&=3\times14+4\\14&=3\times4+2\\4&=2\times2.\end{align}Since the remainder of the last division is $0$, $\gcd(46,14)=2$ and a way of expressing $2$ as $46x+14y$ with $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ can be obtained from the previous computations:\begin{align}2&=14-3\times4\\&=14-3\times(46-3\times14)\\&=10\times14-3\times46.\end{align}And this technique always works.